# Documentation missing for the requests_timeout parameter of GCSFileSystem

Tags: google-cloud-platform, code-documentation, google-cloud-filestore

The Google Cloud [GCFSFileSystem](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gcsfs.core.GCSFileSystem) object takes a `requests_timeout` parameter with a default value of None. This parameter is not documented.

I assume this is the time before we give up on an individual GCFS request. By analogy with `cache_timeout`, which is documented, I assume it is a float value in seconds, where `None` means no timeout.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integer value in seconds:

Extract from the google.auth.transport.requests [documentation](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/google/auth/transport/requests.html):

```
timeout (Optional[int]): The number of seconds to wait for a
                response from the server. If not specified or if None, the
                requests default timeout will be used.
```

Which is called on line 490, according to the `gcsfs.core` [documentation](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/gcsfs/core.html#GCSFileSystem).

**Edit:** The default timeout is 120 seconds as defined by `_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT` (*credits to [@John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) for adding this info*)

Comment: To add to this good answer. The default timeout is 120 seconds as defined by `_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT`.

Comment: @JohnHanley , Thanks for improving the answer - you are always precise in the answers and comments that I run into. I can incorporate this info in the answer if you agree.